# Observe changes in internal array Ember Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I want to observe changes inside an Ember object created inside an Ember Service.

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
  internalCache: Ember.Object.create(),

  setInternalCache: function setTestObj(itemId, relation, content) {
    let arr, myarr, ref, internalCache;
    internalCache = this.get('internalCache');

    if (!((ref = internalCache[itemId]) != null ? ref[relation] : void 0)) {
      internalCache[itemId] || (internalCache[itemId] = {});
      internalCache[itemId][relation] = [];
    }

    arr = Ember.copy((internalCache[itemId][relation]), false);
    content.map(function (elem) {
      return arr.pushObject(elem);
    });

    myarr = internalCache[itemId][relation];
    myarr.replace(0, arr.length, Ember.copy(arr, false));
  }});
```

The **internalCache** object properties can be observed, but this object will be eventually be filled with an internal object with several properties to be arrays. I want to observe changes when elements are added/removes on those arrays. Say a structure like:

```
internalCache: {
  "identifier12": {
    attachments: [1, 2],
    children: [ ... ]
  }
}
```

The **attachments** array property is set using the **setInternalCache** function and it successfully modifies the **attachments** array property inside the **identifier12** property of **internalCache**.

What I've tried so far:

```
cache: Ember.inject.service('cache');

itemAttachmentsObserver: Ember.observer('cache.internalCache.identifier12', function() {
  console.log('foo');
}).on('init')
```

To see if nested modified props would trigger the observer, nothing.

```
itemAttachmentsObserver: Ember.observer('cache.internalCache.identifier12.@each', function() {
  console.log('bar');
}).on('init')
```

and

```
itemAttachmentsObserver: Ember.observer('cache.internalCache.identifier12.@each.attachments.[]', function() {
  console.log('baz')
}).on('init')
```

But I can't make the observer trigger when the **attachments** array is modified.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested something to play around and it seems to work, just in case somone stumbles upon the same problem:

```
    itemAttachmentsObserver: Ember.observer('cache.internalCache.identifier12.attachments.@each', function () {
      var cache = this.get('cache');
    }).on('init'),
```

And it fires in this case.